# Detect bold text in a cell & add " Total" after these titles

Tags: excel, vba

I want all the bolds titles to have " Total" after the text. I can't tell why the formula isn't working.

Before - this what it looks like
[image]

After - i want it to look like this
[image]

This is the formula that I did and i can't figure whats causing it:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim text As String
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("C1:C2000")
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And cell.Font.Bold Then
            
            For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
                If cell.Characters(Start:=InStr(cell.Value, words(i)), Length:=Len(words(i))).Font.Bold Then
                    words(i) = words(i) & " Total"
        
End Sub
```

Comment: You're modifying the values in an array `words`, not actually changing the values on a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

here I tried this and it worked

```
Sub BoldToCell()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long
        
        
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
        
        
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        
        
        For Each cell In ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
            
            If cell.Font.Bold = True Then
                
                cell.Value = cell.Value & " Total"
            End If
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need nested For loop
- `words` is not assigned any values. Using `Option Explicit` can help avoid this type of mistake.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'modify as needed
    Set rng = ws.Range("C1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And cell.Font.Bold Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & " Total"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```